# Ratchet Modal bug on iOS 8

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, css, ios8, ratchet

I have an app on the store which is built using [Ratchet](http://goratchet.com) framework. It used to work fine, until iOS 8 was released. Now when I test it on iOS 8, title bars for modals won't appear. All the controls like `Close`, `Back` buttons on the bar work when I click, but the bar and the controls on it are not visible. This happens only on iOS 8, works fine on iOS 7 and older versions.

To reproduce this bug, please open this sample app http://goratchet.com/examples/app-android-notes in Safari on an iOS 8 device or simulator, and then click on *New note* button to open a modal.

I've noticed while debugging it in Safari's web inspector that if I move the bar `<header>...</header>` element of the modal to somewhere else and then bring it back to its original position, it appears. Or sometimes, changing its `display` property from `block` to `none` and then back to `block` works. Or sometimes if I scroll the page.

Any solution will be highly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is an issue with `position: fixed` in Safari as discussed in this SO question: [Mobile safari position:fixed z-index glitch when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832531/mobile-safari-positionfixed-z-index-glitch-when-scrolling)

You can fix it by adding this rule to your CSS

```
header.bar.bar-nav {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

You can track the issue on Ratchet's Github repository here - https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/679

Answer (score 1):

You should try `position:sticky;`. It's made to deal with `position` on Safari. `fixed` has been an issue with mobile devices for years. I thought it was fixed but iOs8 has weird behavior too...

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit